# Find all positive three - digit integers $\overline{abc}$ such that $\overline{abc}=5abc$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Number is divisible by $5$ if the last digit is $0$ or $5$. Since $c\neq 0$, $c=5$.

Using brute force (checking each combination with three digits), I get that the only solution is $175$ :  $a=1,b=7,c=5$.

How to solve a problem efficiently?

Comment: Just to be clear: $\overline{abc}$ means that $a,b,c$ are the digits of a three-digit number, while $abc$ is the product of the three numbers $a,b,c$?

Comment: @Arthur, Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already know that $c=5$.

Hence $100a+10b+5=25ab$.

Hence $20a+2b+1=5ab$.

$20a+2b+1$ is odd.

Hence $5ab$ is odd.

Hence $5ab$ ends with $5$.

Hence $20a+2b+1$ ends with $5$.

Hence $2b+1$ ends with $5$.

Hence $2b$ ends with $4$.

Hence $b=2$ or $b=7$.

Since $5ab$ is odd, $b$ must be odd.

Hence $b=7$.

Hence $20a+2\cdot7+1=5a\cdot7$.

Hence $a=1$.

Comment: From $20a+2b+1=5ab $ we have $5|2b+1\implies 5|2b-4=2(b-2)\implies 5|b-2\implies (b=2 \lor b=7)$.

Answer (score 3):

Once you have $c=5$, it becomes clear that $100a+10b+5=25ab$. Manipulating this, we have:
$$
0=5ab-20a-2b-1=5a(b-4)-2(b-4)-8-1\implies \color{blue}{\boxed{9=(5a-2)(b-4)}}.
$$
Note that $5a-2$ can only be $-2$, $3$, $8$ or bigger than $9$. We conclude that $5a-2=3=b-4$, yielding the answer you have found.